# Generate lua parameters for C#

Tags: c#, command-line, parameters, lua, transfer

I made an application in ***C#***, where I open a virtual keyboard. I also have a ***Lua*** application that runs this keyboard, and both are functional. In this scenario I needed to send some information from ***Lua*** to ***C#*** by the command line, but I'm not having success, does anyone know if it is possible, and if so, how could I do it?

Code ***Lua-***

`os.execute('C:\Users\Public\Documents\Keyboard.exe')`

The code just calls the executable.

Code ***C#-***

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2

{
    static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Test if input arguments were supplied.
            if (args.Length >= 0)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }



            Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Keyboard());
        }
    }
}
```

Here I read the console, but I'm not sending any code through ***Lua*** to read through ***C#***, in this case I wanted to send a parameter through lua, and receive it through ***C#***, but I don't know how to implement this through ***Lua***.

Comment: Are the two processes started separately or starts one the other?

Comment: @Ackdari, the ```Lua``` process runs the executable generated by ```C#```

Comment: Then please add code examples of how you start the c# program and how the two currently interact

Comment: Do you have any attempts you can add to the question? this can help us pinpoint what went wrong with your attempts at a solution

Comment: Actually as far as I did it is working, but I can't implement a part of sending a parameter and receiving it in ***C#***.

Comment: `os.execute([[C:\Users\Public\Documents\Keyboard.exe arg1 arg2 arg3]])`